# adding white space between clean string functions

Tags: php, javascript, html

I've got the following code which outputs two different strings sent from a php contact form.

```
$email_message .= "Module: ".clean_string($modcode_1_from)."\s".clean_string($modcode_2_from)."\r\n";
```

is meant to display module code 1 and module code 2.

Currently looks likes this

1001\s2002

However i want it to look like:

1001 2002

So i added \s to add white space between the strings but it does not do anything for me.

Comment: Use `$email_message .= "Module: ".clean_string($modcode_1_from)." ".clean_string($modcode_2_from)."\r\n";`. I removed the `\s` and put a space in its place. Try that and let me know if it worked.

Comment: Why not just a normal space? `$email_message .= "Module: ".clean_string($modcode_1_from)." ".clean_string($modcode_2_from)."\r\n";`

Comment: Whitespace is just a general term referring to spaces, tabs, newlines, and other similar characters. You don't add **whitespace** - you probably just want to add a space. Use `" "` instead of `"\s"`.

Answer (score 1):

use non-breaking space `&nbsp;` or you can use `\t` to add a tab char. And the best one is just a space:

```
$email_message .= "Module: " . clean_string($modcode_1_from). "&nbsp;". clean_string($modcode_2_from) . "\r\n";


$email_message .= "Module: " . clean_string($modcode_1_from) . "\t" . clean_string($modcode_2_from) . "\r\n";


$email_message .= "Module: " . clean_string($modcode_1_from) . " " . clean_string($modcode_2_from) . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use this:**

```
$email_message .= "Module: ".clean_string($modcode_1_from)." ".clean_string($modcode_2_from)."\r\n";
```

**What I did:** I removed the `\s` and put a space in its place.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** DO NOT USE `"&nbsp;"`, it will echo/add `&nbsp;` between `1001` and `2002`.

Resulting in: 
`1001&nbsp;2002`

Therefore, replace `\s` with an actual space using your spacebar.

**Footnote (other options):**

If you wish to later use your data in Excel for example, you could use a comma `,` 
(CSV, comma seperated value) as the seperating character or a tab for a tab-seperated value `\t` i.e. `"\t"`, or a semi-colon `;` i.e. `"; "`.

You may need/want to add a space after the comma; i.e. `", "` for use as a CSV.

Example output of using a comma: `1001, 1002`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the \s to

```
'&nbsp;'
```

and see if this works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$email_message .= "Module: ".clean_string($modcode_1_from)." ".clean_string($modcode_2_from)."\r\n";
```